# Flutter syncfusion_flutter_pdf package

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I would like to show an image from firebase with syncfusion_flutter_pdf but I couldn't do it. I used exact same code block from official documentation but it didn't help me too.

The documentation gives the code below but there are no spesific way for Network image or something[image]

Can anyone have an idea

Comment: get images or put a link from firebase images

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use flutter printing package [flutter printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

```
const imageProvider = const NetworkImage('https/image.png');
final image = await    flutterImageProvider(imageProvider);

doc.addPage(pw.Page(
build: (pw.Context context) {
  return pw.Center(
    child: pw.Image(image),
  ); // Center
})); // Page
```

Comment: But it's not the pdf package. Can't use pw object right?

Comment: Just import printing package and use as above code

Comment: use printing package only to get the flutterImageProvider function, Get the pw object from flutter pdf package